# Firebase Crashlytics is not able to deobfuscate crash description

Tags: java, android, firebase, obfuscation, crashlytics

In my application I'm using firebase crashlytics. My Codes are obfuscated. I've added this lines in proguard, to get my stack trace deobfuscated.

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable        # Keep file names and line numbers.
-keep public class * extends java.lang.Exception  # Optional: Keep custom exceptions.
```

Now it can to deobfuscate my stack trace, but not the crash description. It still throws e.g. `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'myapp.shared.Repository g.a.e.e.u(java.lang.Class)' on a null object reference`.
Is there a way to make crashlytics also deobfuscate my crash description, not only stack trace?

Comment: Do you have a screenshot that depicts this?

Comment: For now, Retrace is probably the best way to solve this https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/tools/retrace